# How Can I Find the Range of a Function in Sympy

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, sympy

I'm getting started with Sympy and I have some questions. I have a function and I would like to find the domain (all possible `x` values for `f`) and the range (all possible `y` values for `f`) of that function, I have already been able to get the function domain using `continuous_domain` but I can't find a way of getting the range.

This is an example function:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Symbol, S
from sympy.calculus.util import continuous_domain

x = Symbol("x")
f = sin(x)/x
domain = continuous_domain(f, x, S.Reals)
print(domain)
```

Is there any way in Sympy to get the range of a function, if not, how would you accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same `util.py` you can import `function_range` and use that. In general, solve `f(x) = y` for `x` and find the continuous domain of that.

```
>>> solve(x**2 - 1 - y,x)
[-sqrt(y + 1), sqrt(y + 1)]
>>> [continuous_domain(i,y,S.Reals) for i in _]
[Interval(-1, oo), Interval(-1, oo)]
```

But that requires that you be able to solve the expression...which is not always possible as for `sin(x)/x` (and that is why `function_range` will fail for that).